Which abelian groups and odd integers lead to a well-posed weights puzzle?
Consider the following puzzle (which I quote from here):

In a collection of 101 balls, each ball weighs a whole number of pounds. If any one is removed from the collection, the remaining balls can be divided into two groups of 50 balls each with the total weight of all balls in the first group equal to the total weight of all the balls in the second group. Prove that all of the balls weigh the same.

Now, this puzzle still makes sense if we generalize from $101$ to any odd integer $2n+1$ and if we allow weights from any abelian group $A$, not just $\mathbb{Z}$.
The standard solution is indifferent about the number of balls, but the underlying group in question does play a role for the argument, (which depends crucially on the notion of parity). Hence, the question arises
Which choices of $A$ and $2n+1$ lead to a well-posed puzzle?
Below the fold I give my thoughts and partial progress that lead to a more refined question at the end.

As a first observation, note that the puzzle for $A\oplus B$ is well-posed if and only if both $A$ and $B$ already work (for any given $2n+1$). Now, the subgroup generated by the (finitely many) weights is a sum of cyclic groups and therefore gives rise to a valid puzzle if and only if each cyclic summand does. This reduces the question to ($\mathbb{Z}$ and) cyclic groups of prime power order.
Moreover, the puzzle on $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ is valid for any $k$ if and only if the one on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ already is:
First, any nonconstant solution for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ can be scaled up into $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$, showing the first implication. On the other hand, assume that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ gives a valid puzzle and we have some solution for $A=\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$. Start by subtracting the value of any ball from each one, which will still give a solution. Projecting these new weights to $A/pA$ then gives a solution for the quotient, which must be constant by assumption. Since one of the weights is zero, they must therefore all lie inside $pA\simeq \mathbb{Z}/p^{k-1}\mathbb{Z}$. By induction on $k$, we are done.
This directly implies that the puzzle with $2n+1$ balls weighted in $A$ is valid if and only if $A$ has no $p_i$-torsion for some collection of primes $\{p_i\}$ (that may depend on $n$).
As such, we may from now on just focus on the puzzle on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p$.
An adaptation of the original solution works to show that both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ lead to valid puzzles for any odd number of balls:
We can start by subtracting the value of any specific ball from each one in the group. This still gives a valid configuration. Let $B$ be the subgroup generated by all values of the new weights. Omitting the ball with value $0$, we can split the remaining balls into two, so that their sum $S$ must be in $2B$. Now, if $B\neq 0$, there must exist some ball with weight $b\notin 2B$. But leaving that ball out will leave a remaining sum of $S-b$, which can not be split into two values, a contradiction. Thus, we must have $B=0$, so that each ball now has value $0$ (and they all started with the same weight).
This little argument does not work if $2B=B$, and indeed there are counterexamples as soon as $2n+1\geq 5$ (the cases $1$ and $3$ being trivially true).
Concretely, we can take $A=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and pick a single ball of weight $0$ along with an even split of $1$'s and $2$'s. It is not hard to see that this gives a valid configuration.
However, the failing of the above argument is not a guarantee that there will be nonconstant solutions $-$ indeed just a little bit of fiddling shows that the only (cyclic) counterexamples with $5$ balls have values in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.
Beyond this, I know nothing. Therefore I pose the refined question
Given $2n+1\geq 7$, which primes $p$ allow for a nonconstant solution with weights in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$? Are there always only finitely many?
Thanks for any insights into this!

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105400/extending-an-assignment-property-from-q-to-r-or-c

@GerryMyerson I did have a look, thanks for the pointer! At the moment I don't have access to the paper mentioned there, but it seems as though it answers a slightly different question to mine (which is still interesting partial progress though). (Also, didn't we have more or less this exact exchange yesterday already? What happened to the comments ...?)
